# .htaccess ignored in child directory

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have the following .htaccess kept in the root of the website i am trying to use it in

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 405 /error.php
ErrorDocument 408 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
ErrorDocument 502 /error.php
ErrorDocument 504 /error.php
```

the structure i have is root = website.com/httpdocs

i want a custom page error.php kept in the root to display my errors

when i go to the url www.website.com/dir/ i get a message "File not found" which is not my custom error.php additionally the directory has an index.php file that it should read

i attempted adding

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

to the .htaccess file and i still got the "File not found"

i cannot figure out
1) why my custom error page is not read
2) why the index.php is not being read
3) why is both rewrite conditions working

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the .php file exists, modify your htaccess like this :

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 405 /error.php
ErrorDocument 408 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
ErrorDocument 502 /error.php
ErrorDocument 504 /error.php


RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ /$1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: it yeilds the same result

Comment: Do you have another htaccess file in the subfolder?

Comment: it is the only one

Comment: then how are the rewrite conditions firing? does /error.php = www.website.com/error.php or is /error.php relative

Comment: What do you mean by rewriteConditions?

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ /$1.php [NC,L]  y urls read about instead of about.php and if you go to http it kicks you to https

Comment: i am using plesk if that does ne thing

Comment: Please read the apache's official documentation 


https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html